# How to fix react-native-date-picker in iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Who can explain this to me? I am using the react-native-date-picker but when I run the app with different versions of iOS devices they show a different date picker style. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: This is expected behaviour as iOS 14 introduced a new native date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard React Native UI components based on a target platform ones and they can be different on different platforms or different platform versions. Simply saying React Native provides you a bridge to manage a current native UI control.

iOS has `UIDatePicker` native control that implements the inputting of date and time values and it has been changed several times (https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/new-uidatepicker-ios14/). So if you want to have the same appearance of the date picker you should create your own pure RN component or use any open source one.